# SSD and intel i5 lagging

Tags: windows-7, ssd, lag, intel-core-i5

My "new" notebook has some really wierd lags during work, youtube video etc etc... Sometimes it has bluescreen during booting, sometimes after reboot. All my drivers are updated and SSD firmware too.

This is my notebook parameters:

```
Operating System
MS Windows 7 64-bit SP1
CPU
Intel Core i5 @ 2.40GHz: 57 °C
Sandy Bridge 32nm Technology
RAM
8,00 GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 665MHz (9-9-9-24)
Motherboard
LENOVO 12985VG (CPU): 58 °C
Graphics
SyncMaster (1680x1050@60Hz)
AMD Radeon HD 6630M Series (Lenovo)
Hard Drives
125 GB Crucial M4-CT128M4SSD1 ATA Device (SATA-SSD)
```

Full specs here: http://speccy.piriform.com/results/Khr265gWVgk6vKTMrhdfhlS

Comment: What's the blue screen you're getting? When it lags what does the CPU and disk activity look like?

Comment: Bluescreen is displayed for 0,1 second... So I really dont know what it is about... And the lags are really random and I can not watch all day my CPU and HDD activity..

Comment: Marek, you can find bluescreen information in the event log (look for bugcheck).

Answer (score 0):

Have you run chdsk? If you are blue screening, it sounds like a disk error.

Comment: result: "Windows has checked the file system and found no problems."

Answer (score 0):

The blue screens could be due to faulty hardware, it may be worth sending it back.

Having a fast CPU and disk won't eliminate all lags. Some programs will hang whilst trying to make a network connection (IE and unavailable proxies are guilty of this) which will really slow down your experience no matter how fast everything else is.

Comment: Ok, I will try to close some network programs.

Answer (score 0):

When starting Windows press <kbd>F8</kbd> (or repeatedly hit it until the boot menu appears) and start the memory diagnostic from there (should be under »Repair my computer« or something). I recently had random file corruption on the hard drive as well as five blue screens in two days (which is about five times as much as I expect for the lifetime of the system itself). It was caused by a faulty RAM module.